# Are father daughter relationships forbidden under 7 laws of Noach?

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws, noahidism

Under the sub laws of Noach

http://noahide.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/The-Noahide-Dinim-sub-Laws.html

8 "Against [a man] lying carnally with his father."
Negative Mitzvah 351
Leviticus 18:7 "Do not act immodestly with your father"

Although I'm not sure if this also means it's prohibited for a daughter to do the same, and in the other relations mentioned there I didn't see a mention of a original for father to daughter, only from son to mother

So is it prohibited to bnei Noach, or not? I wasn't able to find an explicit source

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a dispute in Sanhedrin exactly which relationships are forbidden to Benei Noach.

[Sanhedrin 58b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.58b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) brings the following statement of Rav Hunah:

> אמר רב הונא כותי מותר בבתו
>
> Rav Huna says: A gentile is permitted to marry his daughter.

[**Rashi** there](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.58b.9.1?lang=bi) explains that this statement is according to all opinions. The **Ein Mishpat** there cites the **Rambam** ([Hilchos Melachim 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.9.5?lang=bi), [Hilchos Issurei Biah 14:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.14.10?lang=bi)), who lists all the prohibited relationships to Benei Noach. He didn't list marrying a daughter. The **Ein Mishpat** therefore understood that the **Rambam** ruled like Rav Huna. The [**Maharsha**](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chidushei_Halachot_on_Sanhedrin.58b.1?lang=bi) there also says this.

Comment: Worth perhaps noting the Ramban by the daughters of Lot (Gen. 19:32) citing Nazir 23 still considers it disgusting.